# How can i check database if exist from in array

Tags: php, mysql

i try to check before insert database if values exist in database row.

this is my code. i want to check in array values if have in database. if exist "kullanici" and "totoid" dont insert to database.

```
            if($sonuc == 1) {
                $arr[] = '(
                                "' . $mac->kullanici . '",
                                "5",
                                "' . $mac->totoid  . '"
                        )';
            }
            if($sonuc == 2) {
                $arr[] = '(
                                "' . $mac->kullanici . '",
                                "10",
                                "' . $mac->totoid  . '"
                        )';
            }
            if($sonuc == 3) {
                $arr[] = '(
                                "' . $mac->kullanici . '",
                                "15",
                                "' . $mac->totoid  . '"
                        )';
            }
            if($sonuc == 4) {
                $arr[] = '(
                                "' . $mac->kullanici . '",
                                "20",
                                "' . $mac->totoid  . '"
                        )';
            }
            if($sonuc == 5) {
                $arr[] = '(
                                "' . $mac->kullanici . '",
                                "25",
                                "' . $mac->totoid  . '"
                        )';
            }
        }

        $sql = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO kazananlar (kullanici, kazanci, totoid) VALUES " . implode(',', $arr));
```

[image]

Comment: Implode like you do in VALUES

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the [`insert... on duplicate key` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). The upside of this technique is you can use a single query, so you do not have to worry about possible race conditions.

This works by first creating a unique constraint on columns `kullanici` and `totoid`:

```
create unique index idx_kazananlar on kazananlar(kullanici, totoid);
```

Then, you can do:

```
insert into kazananlar (kullanici, kazanci, totoid) 
values (...)
on duplicate key update kullanici = values(kullanici)
```

The database checks if a row already exists with the same `kullanici` and `totoid`; if it does, then the `on duplicate keys` clause performs a no-op.

Comment: i dont want update. bcs later i will add new point to user with new TOTOID. is it possible?

Comment: @Kritik: it updates to a value that is already there. So this is really a no-op (it will not change the existing row).

Comment: so. how  i can write this for to values? check totoid and kullanici later run on duplicate.

Comment: @Kritik: that's what the query does. You can read the documentatin that I linked in my answer, and give a try to the query in your application.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'keys update set kullanici = values(kullanici)' at line 25

INSERT INTO kazananlar (kullanici, kazanci, totoid) VALUES ( "s3dfsaa", "25", "47196" ),( "asdasda", "25", "47196" ),( "awdaw", "15", "47196" ),( "324324234", "20", "47196" ),( "admin", "5", "47196" ),( "aslan Akbey", "10", "47196" ) on duplicate keys update set kullanici = values(kullanici)  its give like this error.

Comment: @Kritik: sorry, there were typos in the syntax. Fixed just now.